# Set Spark Config property for spark-testing-base

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-spark, pyspark

While I was trying to use [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) in Python, I needed to test a function which writes on a Postgres DB.

To do so is necessary to provide to the Spark Session the Driver to connect to Posgtres; to achieve that I first tried to override the `getConf()` [method](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/python/sparktestingbase/sqltestcase.py) (as reported in the comment `Override this to specify any custom configuration.`). But apparently it doesn't work. Probably I'm not passing the value with the required syntax or whatever but after many attempts I anyway get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver` (typical of when the Driver Jar was not correctly downloaded through the conf parameter).

Attempted `getConf` override:

```
    def getConf(self):
        return ("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1")

    def getConf(self):
        return {"spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1"}

    def getConf(self):
        return SparkConf()\
            .setMaster("local[*]")\
            .setAppName("test")\
            .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1")
```

So I even tried to Override `the setUp()` method like that:

```
    def setUp(self):
        try:
            from pyspark.sql import Session
            self.session = Session.Builder.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1")
            self.sqlCtx = self.session._wrapped
        except Exception:
            self.sqlCtx = SQLContext(self.sc)
```

But still no luck. So what I am doing wrong? How am I supposed to override the `getConf()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to override the setUpClass method:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    """Setup a basic Spark context for testing"""
    class_name = cls.__name__
    conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1")
    cls.sc = SparkContext(cls.getMaster(), appName=class_name, conf=conf)
    quiet_py4j()
```

And in this way is then possible to pass to the Spark test library external jars.

Credits to Leonardo Noleto: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/281#event-2200108290

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how to do this in python. In scala, using sbt, it is quite straight forward. But anyways, the `System.setProperty("spark.jars.packages", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1")` method found here: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/187 worked for me.

So I would rec looking up how to do that with python + spark.

Comment: thanks for your answer @r0bb23 . I already noticed that thread for Scala, indeed I opened an issue in that repository as well https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/281 but I am looking for a solution in Python